# How to increase boot disk space?

Tags: centos6, google-compute-engine

While creating a compute engine in google cloud , I assigned persistent disk as 50 GB. However my local disk shows as 10 GB , which is almost full. Help me increase this disk space. guide me how persistent disk(50 GB, one I created) is used here !

[Snapshot of boot disk and persistent disk of 50 GB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMIg4.jpg)

Comment: not sure, how to delete this question.  Please ignore

Comment: `fdisk -l`? Does this show that you have a 10GB, or a 50GB disk attacked?

Comment: The steps to resize disk partition is documented on this link (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#resizing_disk_paritions_on_linux_instances)

Answer (score 1):

Almost all the OS on GCE supports automatic resizing and CentOS 6 is one of them. After increasing the disk size through Cloud Console or gcloud CLI, you need to reboot the instance to automatically recognize the new disk size.

If your OS doesn't recognized the new disk size, then you will need to follow the steps indicated at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resizing_disk_paritions_on_linux_instances). The list of OS on GCE that support automatic resizing are listed in [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-root-persistent-disks#autoresize).

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps in you have single xfs (/dev/sda1) partition.

First re-create your root partition, type this command:

```
(echo d; echo n; echo p; echo 1; echo ; echo; echo w) | sudo fdisk /dev/sda
```

Then restart your server.
Once restarted, grow your partition

```
xfs_growfs /dev/sda1
```

Verify with:

```
df -h
```

**Don`t forget to make snapshot before trying!**